# How to set data flatlist with Mobx?

Tags: react-native, axios, mobx, asyncstorage

I'm new to mobx. I'm trying to transfer data to the **FlatList** from the **favorites store** to the **favoritescreen** side with mobx, but the flatlist appears empty, why?

***The reason why I use listData() in the bookmarkList is that if I don't use the arrow function in the bookmarkList, it gives me the following error;***

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.userId')]
```

**favorites(store);**

```
import { observable, computed, action, makeObservable, configure } from "mobx";
import { bookmarkApi, petApi } from '../../constants/apiURL';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

configure({
    enforceActions: "never",
})

class Favorites {
    userId = 0;
    petList = [];

    constructor() {
        this.bookMarkList()

        makeObservable(this, {
            userId: observable,
            petList: observable,
            bookMarkList: action,
        })
    }

    bookMarkList = async () => {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId')
        if (value != null) {

            this.userId = value;

            listData = () => {
                bookmarkApi.get('/').then(function (responseJson) {
                    if (responseJson) {
                        this.petList = responseJson.data.filter(data => data.userId == this.userId)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

export const favoriteStore = new Favorites();
```

**FavoriteScreen.js**

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { favoriteStore } from '../store/favorites';

function FavoriteScreen() {

    const {userId, petList} = favoriteStore;

    const Item = ({ petName }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{petName}</Text>
        </View>
    );


    const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <Item petName={item.petName} />
    );

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={petList}
                keyExtractor={item => item.bookmarkId}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
export default observer(FavoriteScreen);
```

Comment: You just asked the same question yesterday, no? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074073/how-to-set-array-value-in-react-native-mobx

Comment: actually not. it's not getting error but still not data in flatlist :) @Danila

Comment: Ok then. Right now in your example your code does nothing basically. You assign some arrow function to `listData` and that is it. You never invoke it. Is that intended?

Comment: yes because I can't call listdata function. because that function is inside the bookMarkList. The reason why I wrote a listData function was that I needed to use the arrow function as in the answer you gave in the previous topic. @Danila

Comment: my request is to assign data from listData to FlatList but somehow i can't @Danila

Comment: I said you need to use arrow function instead of `function` inside `bookmarkApi.get('/').then` callback.

Answer (score 0):

I solved

instead of:

```
listData = () => {
            bookmarkApi.get('/').then(function (responseJson) {
                if (responseJson) {
                    this.petList = responseJson.data.filter(data => data.userId == this.userId)
                }
            })
        }
```

like this:

```
  bookmarkApi.get('/').then(bookmarks => {
        this.petList = bookmarks.data.filter(data => data.userId == this.userId)
    })
```

Comment: I mean, you just used my solution, no? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70074073/how-to-set-array-value-in-react-native-mobx I'll mark this question as duplicate

Comment: i just used like this

Comment: bookmarkApi.get('/').then(bookmarks => {
        this.petList = bookmarks.data.filter(data => data.userId == this.userId)
    })

Comment: i think its ur solution:)